# How does Laravel decide where to save temp files?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, laravel-5, laravel-medialibrary

I am using [this](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-medialibrary) image library that uploads images to S3.

At first it saves the image as a temp file on local machine, then it uploads it to S3.

My issue is that using certain functions temp files get uploaded to `C:\\xampp\\tmp/` and using other functions the temp file gets uploaded to `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp`.

My question is that where does this gets decided? and how to configure it?

I'm using Win10 machine and Postman.

This is the function that uploads the image to `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\Local\Temp`:

```
 * @param Request $request
 *
 * @throws \Spatie\MediaLibrary\Exceptions\FileCannotBeAdded
 */
public function coverPhotoFromRequest( Request $request ) {
  if ( $request->hasFile( 'cover_photo' ) ) {
    $this->clearMediaCollection( 'cover' );
    $this->addMedia( $request->file( 'cover_photo' ) )->toMediaCollection( 'cover' );
  }
}
```

This very similar function uploads temp files to `C:\\xampp\\tmp/`:

```
/**
 * @helper handles the profile photo from request or link
 *
 * @param mixed $photo
 *
 * @return \Spatie\MediaLibrary\Media
 * @throws \Spatie\MediaLibrary\Exceptions\FileCannotBeAdded
 * @throws \Spatie\MediaLibrary\FileAdder\FileDoesNotExist
 */
public function profilePhoto( $photo = null ) {
  if ( Ut::isUrl( $photo ) ) {
    return $this->clearMediaCollection( 'profile' )->addMediaFromUrl( $request->file( 'profile_photo' ) )->toMediaCollection( 'profile' );
  }

  if ( $photo instanceof UploadedFile ) {
    return $this->clearMediaCollection( 'profile' )->addMedia( $request->file( 'profile_photo' ) )->toMediaCollection( 'profile' );
  }
}
```

This is the path to project:

```
C:\Users\myUser\Projects\images\api
```

The problem is that when I push the code to the server, the same problem happens.

I checked config file and I have this:

```
'temporary_directory_path' => storage_path('medialibrary/temp'),
```

But sometimes it still sends to `/xampp` and `C:\Users\myUser\AppData\`

Comment: what does the documentation say? It mentions a config file where a temp file location can be specified

Comment: Thank you. I set it storage_path('medialibrary/temp') but it still behaves the same. I ran cache and config clear and composer dump-autoload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library has a config directive for the temp path 'temporary_directory_path' listed in the docs https://docs.spatie.be/laravel-medialibrary/v7/installation-setup.

Does setting that help?

Comment: Thank you. It is set to null and I set it to storage_path('medialibrary/temp') but still sends to locations outside project directory.

Comment: Does the directory that storage_path('medialibrary/temp') resolves to actually exist? Have you checked the (error) logging to see if there are any 'folder does not exist' type messages?